# Drop Perpendicular lines to axis from points

Tags: pgfplots, line

I would like to get two plots such that there are perpendicular lines from each point to either the x-axis (on one plot) and perpendicular lines to the y-axis on the other.  Like this:

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}


\newcommand{\datapthreeone}{prob3.dat}
\begin{filecontents*}{\datapthreeone}
    x1     y1  averX  averY     Ex     Ey
 2.000,  3.000, -0.714,  1.000,  1.000, -0.714
 1.000,  2.000, -1.714,  0.000,  0.000, -1.714
 1.000,  1.000, -1.714, -1.000, -1.000, -1.714
 2.000,  2.000, -0.714,  0.000,  0.000, -0.714
 4.000,  2.000,  1.286,  0.000,  0.000,  1.286
 4.000,  3.000,  1.286,  1.000,  1.000,  1.286
 5.000,  1.000,  2.286, -1.000, -1.000,  2.286
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2, horizontal sep=4em, vertical sep=5em}]
\nextgroupplot[xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-2.5, ymax=2.5, legend style={font=\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont}, title = (c) PCA Projection Points]
\addplot [only marks, line width = 0.3mm, mark=x, blue, mark options={scale=1.2}]table[x index=4, y index=5, only marks,col sep=comma] {\datapthreeone}; \addlegendentry{\emph{Projected Data}}
\addplot [-latex, dashed, blue, domain=-2:2, samples=2]{0*x + 0};
\addplot[-latex, dashed]coordinates {(-3,0) (2.5,0)};
\addplot[-latex, dashed]coordinates {(0,-2.5) (0,2.5)};

\nextgroupplot[xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-2.5, ymax=2.5, legend style={font=\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont}, title = (c) PCA Projection Points]
\addplot [only marks, line width = 0.3mm, mark=x, blue, mark options={scale=1.2}]table[x index=4, y index=5, only marks,col sep=comma] {\datapthreeone}; \addlegendentry{\emph{Projected Data}}
\addplot [-latex, dashed, blue, domain=-2:2, samples=2]{0*x + 0};
\addplot[-latex, dashed]coordinates {(-3,0) (2.5,0)};
\addplot[-latex, dashed]coordinates {(0,-2.5) (0,2.5)};

\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I found out in the pgfplots manual (http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf):

you need to add the `ycomb` or `xcomb` option in the `\addplot [..] ...` command which in this case it connects coordinates orizontally or vertically. Of course there is a brighter way of writing the right angles code...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,legend style={font=\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\datapthreeone}{prob3.dat}
\begin{filecontents*}{\datapthreeone}
    x1     y1  averX  averY     Ex     Ey
    2.000,  3.000, -0.714,  1.000,  1.000, -0.714
    1.000,  2.000, -1.714,  0.000,  0.000, -1.714
    1.000,  1.000, -1.714, -1.000, -1.000, -1.714
    2.000,  2.000, -0.714,  0.000,  0.000, -0.714
    4.000,  2.000,  1.286,  0.000,  0.000,  1.286
    4.000,  3.000,  1.286,  1.000,  1.000,  1.286
    5.000,  1.000,  2.286, -1.000, -1.000,  2.286
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
    title= (c) PCA Projection Points,
    xmin = -2, xmax =2,ymin=-2.5, ymax=2.5]
        \addplot [only marks, line width = 0.3mm, mark=x, blue, mark options={scale=1.2}]table[x index=4, y index=5, only marks,col sep=comma] {\datapthreeone}; \addlegendentry{\emph{Projected Data}} 
        \addplot[ycomb, red] table[x index=4, y index=5,col sep=comma] {\datapthreeone};

        \addplot [-latex, dashed, blue, domain=-2:2, samples=2]{0*x + 0};
        \addplot[-latex, dashed]coordinates {(-3,0) (2.5,0)};
        \addplot[-latex, dashed]coordinates {(0,-2.5) (0,2.5)};

        \draw[red] (0.9,0) -- (0.9,0.2) -- (1,0.2);
        \draw[red] (-0.1,0) -- (-0.1,0.2) -- (0,0.2);
        \draw[red] (-1.1,0) -- (-1.1,0.2) -- (-1,0.2);
        \draw[red] (-0.9,0) -- (-0.9,-0.2) -- (-1,-0.2);
        \draw[red] (1.1,0) -- (1.1,-0.2) -- (1,-0.2);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title= (c) PCA Projection Points,
    xmin = -2, xmax =2,ymin=-2.5, ymax=2.5]
        \addplot [only marks, line width = 0.3mm, mark=x, blue, mark options={scale=1.2}]table[x index=4, y index=5, only marks,col sep=comma] {\datapthreeone}; \addlegendentry{\emph{Projected Data}}
        \addplot[xcomb, red] table[x index=4, y index=5,col sep=comma] {\datapthreeone};

        \addplot [-latex, dashed, blue, domain=-2:2, samples=2]{0*x + 0};
        \addplot[-latex, dashed]coordinates {(-3,0) (2.5,0)};
        \addplot[-latex, dashed]coordinates {(0,-2.5) (0,2.5)};
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]